# SQLite recursive query to return file path

Tags: sql, sqlite

At the moment I'm developing an application which has to store a file hierarchy (folders and files are not distinguished) in a database. For this  created following table:

```
tbl_files
----------------------------------
|   id   |   name   |   parent   |
----------------------------------
```

The parent field is a foreign to `tbl_files` itself. The main directory has the id `root`. I now want to get the path to a file until the root directory is reached. I thought about to do this with a recursive SQL-Query but I do not know how to "return" the path from the database.

Is a recursive query okay or is it bad practice? And how should I "generate" the path with this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the path entries, use a [recursive CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte).
To combine the names, use [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
WITH RECURSIVE path(level, name, parent) AS (
    SELECT 0, name, parent
    FROM tbl_files
    WHERE id = @MyFileID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT path.level + 1,
           tbl_files.name,
           tbl_files.parent
    FROM tbl_files
    JOIN path ON tbl_files.id = path.parent
),
path_from_root AS (
    SELECT name
    FROM path
    ORDER BY level DESC
)
SELECT group_concat(name, '/')
FROM path_from_root;
```

Comment: Great thank you for this. Can you also please say something about the efficiency of this query method?

Comment: It's just as efficient as if you were looking up the entries manually. But why do you care; do you need to handle millions of paths per second?

Comment: Okay thanks. I never used something like this befor and I thought about recursive stack size and so on but I think for my queries this is not so important.

Comment: How is there a column `parent` in `path` if you're only selecting the name? For me, this query throws an appropriate error: `Error: no such column: path.parent`.

Comment: @mınxomaτ Oops, that column should have indeed been in `path`.